# Showing that $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{1+\sin(x)-\sin^2x}{e^{\sin(x)}+\cos(x)}=\log 2$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I don't see how to prove that
$$\int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{1+\sin(x)-\sin^2(x)}{e^{\sin(x)}+\cos(x)}\,\mathrm dx=\log 2$$
Integrating by parts is of no help. The same with variable change. Should I use Taylor series? But how?

Comment: **Hint:** $\int_a^bf(x)dx= \int_a^b f(a+b-x)dx$

Comment: Is that hint for my problem? I see no help with it. Could you give more details pls?

Answer (score 8):

Hint:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\ln\left(e^{\sin x}+\cos x\right)=\frac{e^{\sin x}\cos x-\sin x}{e^{\sin x}+\cos x}=\cos x-\frac{\cos^2 x+\sin x}{e^{\sin x}+\cos x}.$$